# asp:hyperlink href won't show up even though i populate navigateurl

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

Does anyone know what is wrong with the following two lines of code?  In both cases, there is no href in the anchor links when i view it in the browser:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval(Request.QueryString["conferenceId"], "~/Cms/schedule-edit.aspx?conferenceId={0}&type=workshopStream") %>' Text="Create Workshop Stream"></asp:HyperLink>

<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/Cms/schedule-edit.aspx?conferenceId={0}&type=scheduleItem", Request.QueryString["conferenceId"]) %>' Text="Create Schedule Item"></asp:HyperLink>
```

This exact same code seems to work fine when I put it into the ItemTemplate of a Listview though.  But it doesn't work when used on it's own in an aspx file.

What's wrong with it?

Also if i replace the navigateUrl with a hardcoded string `~/cms/schedule-edit.aspx?conferenceId=2&type=stuff` then the href shows up.  It just doesn't work when i have the Eval or String.Format in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those **HyperLink** server controls are located outside of **DataBound** controls like GridView, there are two problems in our code -

1. You want to use `<%= %>` instead of `<%# %>` which is used in DataBound controls.
2. You cannot use `<%= %>` to set property of a server control. Basically, you cannot mix `runat="server"` with `<%= %>`.

### Solution

```
<a href='<%= String.Format("~/Cms/schedule-edit.aspx?conferenceId={0}&type=scheduleItem", 
    Request.QueryString["conferenceId"]) %>'>Create Workshop Stream</a>
```

Comment: thanks, you naswered another question i was about to research, the difference between <%= and <%#.  two answers in one!

Answer (score 2):

The anchor syntax `NavigateUrl='<%#...%>` is only valid inside a GridView, ListView, etc. When it is not inside such controls, you can set its NavigateUrl property via code. Obviously, you also need to give an ID to your HyperLink.

The markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Create Schedule Item"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The code behind:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/Cms/schedule-edit.aspx?conferenceId={0}&type=scheduleItem", Request.QueryString["conferenceId"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a data-binding expression here. This is denoted in the following syntax:

```
 <%# [code]  %>
```

The code inside is evaluated only when the containing control, or any of its ancestors have their `.DataBind()` method called.

To work this around, you can:

- Call `Page.DataBind()`
  This could have some unwanted consequences if you have other data-bound controls on the page, as this method will cause all of them to have their data-binding events fired. Usually, this approach is applied if you have minimalistic code-behind and the entire page relies on data-binding expressions.
- Give each `HyperLink` an `ID` and call `HyperLinkID.DataBind();`
- Stick to the approach in [codingstill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885584/asphyperlink-href-wont-show-up-even-though-i-populate-navigateurl/20885724#20885724) by setting the `NavigateUrl` property in the code behind of your page/user control.

Comment: I didn't know the Page.DataBind() approach. If Page.DataBind() is called the HyperLink doesn't need to have an ID, right?

Comment: @codingstill, yes, but calling this on the entire page may have undesired effects on the other controls. So, you need to know well what you're doing.